# Azure Functions base images differences / comparison

Tags: azure-functions

The [documentation](https://github.com/azure/azure-functions-docker) shows five types of Docker images:

- (default)
- slim
- appservice
- buildenv
- core-tools

What is the difference of each of those?

Here is an example for Python:

```
3.0-python3.8
3.0-python3.8-slim
3.0-python3.8-appservice
3.0-python3.8-buildenv
3.0-python3.8-core-tools
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `Dockerfile` linked for each, here is how each image is suited (hold true for all languages)

**1. Core (no suffix)**
Functions Runtime and Language Worker in one container. Ready for deployment.

**2. Slim**
While `slim` images are lightweight versions of core images, these containers seem to be the same in many cases

**3. App Service**
Runtime container used for running function apps on Azure Linux App Service Plans.

**4. Build**
Build container used for building native dependencies

**5. Core Tools**
Developer Container which has `func` and `docker` CLIs installed. This is also based on the [dev container image for python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/master/containers/python-3) suitable for development with [VS Code Remote Containers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers).